# Get totals for the same column but where each SELECT alias contains a specific string

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve a total for the same column but where each alias contains a different string? How do I do this, my sub query below fails.

```
SELECT status (
    SELECT COUNT(status) FROM `table`
    WHERE `status` LIKE LOWER('%stage 1%')
    ) AS Stage1,
status (
    SELECT COUNT(status) FROM `table`
    WHERE `status` LIKE LOWER('%stage 1%')
    ) AS Stage2,
status (
    SELECT COUNT(status) FROM `table`
    WHERE `status` LIKE LOWER('%stage 1%')
    ) AS Stage3
FROM `table`
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desire result?

Comment: status field is a VARCHAR containing text as follows this will vary: "We will implement Stage 1 from 07:00 until 22:00 this evening. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the result of a `CASE` statement that aggregates your groups. Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b41b/11/0).

```
SELECT
  CASE
  WHEN status LIKE '%stage 1%' THEN 'stage 1'
  WHEN status LIKE '%stage 2%' THEN 'stage 2'
  WHEN status LIKE '%stage 3%' THEN 'stage 3'
  END as status_group,
  COUNT(*)
FROM statuses
GROUP BY status_group
```

Comment: Ah that is a LOT simpler. How can I fix the output if there is for example no stage 3 value.

Comment: status_group | total  : NULL = 2, stage 1 = 24, stage 2 = 15

Comment: So if a column is NULL assign stage 3 to it

Comment: Ah, I think you want an `ELSE` in the `CASE`. [Updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2924e/1).

Answer (score 2):

If you want three columns, use conditional aggregation.  This is particularly easy in MySQL:

```
select sum(status LIKE LOWER('%stage 1%')) as status1,
       sum(status LIKE LOWER('%stage 2%')) as status2,
       sum(status LIKE LOWER('%stage 3%')) as status3
from `table`;
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works well, I accepted the answer below as it fits my purpose better. I am using the output to a chart and getting the values in one group works better in my application.

Comment: @Grant . . . My reading of your question suggested that you wanted separate columns rather than separate rows.